# How to propagate current value from dom-repeat down to inner dom-if

Tags: javascript, polymer

```
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{days}}" as="item">
        <td class="d">{{formatDay(item)}}</td>
        <template is="dom-if" if="{{ lastDayOfWeek(item) }}">
        </template> 
    </template>
```

In this case, `lastDayOfWeek(item)` is not getting the value which `dom-repeat` has. How to propagate `item` down to `dom-if`?

Comment: btw, "item" is the default item name, so `as="item"` is redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks right to me:

https://jsbin.com/pebidacaku/edit?html,output

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>

<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{days}}">
        <span>{{item}}</span>
        <template is="dom-if" if="{{isThirdDay(item)}}">
          <span>*</span>
        </template>
        <br>
      </template>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-foo',
        properties: {
          days: {
            type: Array,
            value: function() {
              return [
                '1/2/2016',
                '2/4/2016',
                '3/6/2016',
                '4/8/2016'
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        isThirdDay: function(day) {
          return day === this.days[2];
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>

</html>
```

The reason `item` is different for your inner template is possibly caused by `formatDay` modifying `item` before `lastDayOfWeek` gets to it, as demonstrated here:

https://jsbin.com/himulegicu/edit?html,output

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>

<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{days}}">
        <span>{{formatDay(item)}}</span>
        <template is="dom-if" if="{{isThirdDay(item)}}">
          <span>*</span>
        </template>
        <br>
      </template>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-foo',
        properties: {
          days: {
            type: Array,
            value: function() {
              return [{
                value: '1/2/2016'
              }, {
                value: '2/4/2016'
              }, {
                value: '3/6/2016'
              }, {
                value: '4/8/2016'
              }]
            }
          }
        },
        formatDay: function(day) {
          if (day.value === this.days[2].value) {
            day.value = 'changed!!';
          }
          return day.value;
        },
        isThirdDay: function(day) {
          return day.value === '3/6/2016';
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will look into this in the evening and give feedback.

Comment: Ok, actually in my code, formatDay() does not modify item, and lastDayOfWeek() neither. When I console.log(item) in formatDay(), I get the real value, which is different for each iteration. In lastDayOfWeek() however, I only get the first value it ever had. Strange...

Comment: Can you add a jsbin to demo the problem?

Comment: Here is a starting point: https://jsbin.com/bufiquceca/1/edit?html,console,output

Comment: I still don't see the problem. Logging `item.toString()` in `lastDayOfWeek` shows a changing date: https://jsbin.com/jumaqi/edit?html,console,output

Comment: You are right, it works. Why it did not work before, I don't know. Maybe a caching issue... strange. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: It's not in the scope of this question, but I would like to know why the <tr>s in my template dom-if are not put into the html, even the dom-if functions return true. I updated the jsbin right now, in case you have time to take a look.

Comment: I don't see the updated jsbin, but it would be best to create a new question with that jsbin.

Comment: Did so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703371/why-does-the-html-from-template-dom-if-not-get-applied-here