# Why does the html from template dom-if not get applied here

Tags: javascript, polymer

Consider this code:

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="c">
        <tr>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[days]]" as="o">
            <td class$="[[dayClass(o)]]"><span class="d">[[formatDay(o)]]</span></td>
            <template is="dom-if" if="[[lastDayOfWeek(o)]]"></tr>
                <template is="dom-if" if="[[!lastDayOfCalendar(o)]]"><tr></template>
            </template>
        </template>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Why do the `</tr>` and `<tr>` not get applied to the html?

Full JS Bin demo here: https://jsbin.com/dujekefoga/edit?html,output

**Edit:** Fixed JS Bin url

Answer (score 0):

Your table row tags are misplaced, I got closer to your expected result by changing the order in which the tags are placed. Hope this helps you.

https://jsbin.com/quvutugijo/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

At the end, this is what works. And I believe it's the best solution, as it works with two non-nested `dom-if`, and the html is valid.

I just needed to add a function `firstDayOfWeek` which returns true if `item.isoWeekday() === 1`.

```
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[days]]" as="o">
        <template is="dom-if" if="[[firstDayOfWeek(o)]]"><tr></template>
        <td class$="[[dayClass(o)]]"><span class="d">[[formatDay(o)]]</span></td>
        <template is="dom-if" if="[[lastDayOfWeek(o)]]"></tr></template>
    </template>
```